# Simple GET request takes a lot of time to return

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, asynchronous

I'm running Node.js, Handlebars, and Express for this very simple app. The page contains a single button that, when clicked, fires off an asynchronous GET request that should make a `console.log` message appear. When I click the Submit button, the first `console.log` pops up right away, but subsequent presses take a very long time (like minutes). Is this just the nature of asynchronous GET requests, or am I doing something wrong?

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout:'main'});
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('port', 8080);

app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    var context = {};
    res.render('home', context);
});

app.get('/notify',function(reg,res,next){
    console.log('I got a GET request!');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});
```

**home.handlebars**

```
<input type="submit" id="Submit">
```

**main.handlebars**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="scripts/buttons.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

**buttons.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bindButtons);
function bindButtons(){
    document.getElementById('Submit').addEventListener('click', function(event){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/notify", true);
        req.send(null);
        event.preventDefault();
    });        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to http://localhost:8080/notify you'll see the page keeps loading forever and never actually loads.

This is because there is **no response** to your request. In your app, the subsequent requests take too long because there are previous ones still unresponded.

Try adding this to you /notify GET handler after the console.log:

```
res.send('This is a cool message from server');
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!